# Responsive table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I need help with a responsive table. What's needed is to basically have it change to a 'mobile version' upon resizing, however the mobile version is a little different to the main style of it, as the image shows.

[image]

I've currently got this: http://jsfiddle.net/MLsZ8/

HTML:

```
 <table class="crafting">

    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="width:15%">Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%">Ingredients</th>
    <th style="width:205px;">Input &gt; Output</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr>
    <td>Ore Blocks</td>
    <td>Gold Ingots, Iron Ingots, Diamonds and Lapis Lazuli Dye</td>
    <td><img width="204" height="112" title="Crafting Ore Blocks" src="http://www.minecraftxl.com/images/crafting/Crafting-Ore-Blocks1.gif" alt="Crafting Ore Blocs from Ingots" /></td>
    <td>Turn ingots or diamonds into a placeable block. Can be used for storage or to show off.</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
        td {
        border:0;
        }

        table.crafting {
            border-spacing:0;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        .crafting th {
            border:2px solid #f3f3f3;
            padding:5px;
        }
        .crafting td {
            border:2px solid #f3f3f3;
            padding:5px;
            vertical-align:top;
        }
        .crafting tr {
            background:#c6c6c6;
        }
        .crafting-name {
            font-weight:bold;
            border-bottom:0 !important;
            background:#c6c6c6;
        }
        .crafting-ingredients {
            border-top:0 !important;
            border-bottom:0 !important;
            background:#bcbcbc;
        }
        .crafting-img {
            width:205px;
            border-bottom:0 !important;
            border-top:0 !important;
            background:#c6c6c6;
        }
        .crafting-desc {
            border-top:0 !important;
            background:#bcbcbc;
        }
```

Comment: You haven't given any feedback on anyone's answers.  Has the question been resolved?

Comment: Very late in the day here, but for anyone else struggling with, I created a solution for this exact use-case - you'll need to use the 'nat-row' option: https://patrickhurley.co.uk/notanothertable

Answer (score 1):

If you are not opposed to changing the overall format of the HTML, I have a solution that might be a bit easier to handle...

If you change the current table structure to a series of `div` elements, you can nest each table row into a container `div`.

I'll give you an example for one "row":

```
<div class="tableRow">
<div class="columnOne"> content </div>
<div class="columnTwo"> content </div>
<div class="columnThree"> content </div>
<div class="columnFour"> content </div>
</div>
```

Then, using CSS, you could set `.tableRow {width: 100%}`.  From here, you could set the column widths based on your needs.  From your example, it looks like you could do:

```
.columnOne {width: 10%; float: left;}
.columnTwo {width: 15%; float: left;}
.columnThree {width: 30%; float: left;}
.columnFour {width: 45%; float: left;}
```

Then, when you reach your mobile view breakpoint, using a `@media query`, you can do the following:

`.columnOne, .columnTwo, .columnThree, .columnFour {width: 100%}`

This will cause the columns to effectively become rows of `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Full tables

http://jsfiddle.net/2655u/

Option 2

Convert tables to div in used mediaqueries

**HTML**

```
<div class="title">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <div class="ingredients">Ingredients</div>
    <div class="field">Input &gt; Output</div>
    <div class="description">Description</div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
    <div class="name">Ore Blocks</div>
    <div class="ingredients">Gold Ingots, Iron Ingots, Diamonds and Lapis Lazuli Dye</div>
    <div class="field">
        <img width="204" height="112" title="Crafting Ore Blocks" src="http://www.minecraftxl.com/images/crafting/Crafting-Ore-Blocks1.gif" alt="Crafting Ore Blocs from Ingots" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">Turn ingots or diamonds into a placeable block. Can be used for storage or to show off.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    background : #C6C6C6;
    border:2px solid #f3f3f3;
    padding:5px;
    vertical-align : top;
}
div.title {
    text-align : center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
div.name {
    width : 90px;
}
div.ingredients {
    width : 150px;
}
div.field {
    width : 205px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .title {display:none;}
    .responsive div {
        display : block;
        width : auto;
        text-align : center;
        background : white;
    }
    .responsive div.ingredients {background : #C6C6C6;}
    .responsive div.description {background : #C6C6C6;}
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2DTSG/

Comment: While I like this option. I need to use tables not divs since most email clients render it better with old school HTML. +1 for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was also searching for the same one day. Got the following. It follows the same approach, converting columns to rows when getting viewed in smaller device.

http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Before moving ahead see the **[Live Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php)**

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to have two tables: a regular table (with class `full`) and a mobile one (with class `mobile`).  Then you can use a media query to switch between them at a particular screen size.

If your website isn't particularly heavy, this is an approach that will save a lot of headache.

Example fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/QDrPb/

```
.mobile {
    display:none;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .full {
        display:none;
    }
   .mobile {
       display:block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Twitter Bootstrap` is a nice thing to achieve table-responsiveness.

```
http://getbootstrap.com/
```

You have to download it from the above link and add the css file.

After that, apply like this: `http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive`

I hope this may help your need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here simple demo please reffer this link for pure css [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neelu/1nxjbj7s/4/)

```css
/*by Ñ££¿ Upadhyay*/
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;a
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table caption {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 10px;
}
table tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
table th {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-right: 70px;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Statement Summary</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Account</th>
      <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Period</th>
      <th scope="col">Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">04/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
      <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Acount">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
      <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Tables JavaScript Plugin

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../dist/css/table-fluid.css"/>
<script src=".../dist/js/table-fluid.js"></script>

<table class="table-fluid">
  <thead>
  ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Use JavaScript function

```
window.tableFluid('.table-fluid');
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/table-fluid

https://github.com/maestro888/table-fluid

Answer (score -2):

Table cells cannot rearrange they way you want - rows and columns are locked and cannot float. All you can do is change the layout WITHIN each cell. You will need to change your mark-up completely to make that happen.